# onKeyUp is not launching when I press a key

Tags: java, android

I'm trying everytime I press a key to launch a toast, but it seems its dosn't launching it, any idea?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.txtKey);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.etxtKeyboard);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_P:
                Toast.makeText(this, "P pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Android documentation says about an `Activity.onKeyUp()` method:

> Called when a key was released and not handled by any of the views
>   inside of the activity. So, for example, key presses while the cursor
>   is inside a TextView will not trigger the event (unless it is a
>   navigation to another object) because TextView handles its own key
>   presses.

So it seems that you are trying to catch onKeyUp() event when a focus in your `findViewById(R.id.etxtKeyboard);` edit text view.

You can try add code like this in `Activity.onCreate()`:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(
        new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_P:
                        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "P pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }
);
```